# How can i fix my module pattern to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, module-pattern

I have a module in a different file which should essentially carry out my ajax requests for me (this is in ajaxCall.js), I am trying to add this module to the global window object so that i can use it in another file called (basket-page.js), but I get an error stating

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'process' of undefined(…)

**AjaxCall.js**

```
"user strict";
window.ajaxCall = window.ajaxCall || {}
var ajaxCall = (function () {
var api = {
    process: function (destinationUrl, dataToPost, callbackFunction) {
        $.ajax({
            url: destinationUrl,
            data: dataToPost,
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                if (element.length > 0) {
                    callbackFunction(data, element);
                }
            },
            error: function (req, status, errorObj) {
                console.log(status);
            }
        });
    }
}
window.ajaxCall = api;
return api;
})();
```

**basket-page.js**

```
"use strict";

basket = basket || {};

var basket = (function (ajax) {

    var api = {

        init: function () {
            $("#tblBasket").dataTable({
                bFilter: false,
                pageLength: 10,
                paging: true,
                autoWidth: true,
                columns:
                [
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-text", type: "string" },
                    { "orderDataType": "dom-text-numeric" },
                    null
                ],
                fixedColumns: true
            });
        },

        removeBasketProductRow: function (data, element) {
            if (data === true) {
                element.remove();
            }
        }

    };

    $("#btnRemoveBasketProduct").click(function() {
        var product = $(this).closest("tr");
        var productId = product.attr("id");
        window.ajaxCall.process("/Products/RemoveBasketProduct", productId, api.removeBasketProductRow);
    });

    return api;

})(window);

$(document).ready(function () {
    basket.init();
});
```

Comment: Why are you doing `window.ajaxCall = api;` and then returning `api` for the IIFE ?

Comment: And it's `"use strict";`, furthermore the variable `element` in your `success` is undefined

Comment: Are you sure both files are loaded when you try to execute the function?

Comment: @empiric the user strict is a type, the second file has the right string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was making sure i had my other script file loaded already, since this is what adds object to the global window object.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the function wrapping.  It's unnecessary.

```
"user strict";
window.ajaxCall =  {
    process: function (destinationUrl, dataToPost, callbackFunction) {
        $.ajax({
            url: destinationUrl,
            data: dataToPost,
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
                if (element.length > 0) {
                    callbackFunction(data, element);
                }
            },
            error: function (req, status, errorObj) {
                console.log(status);
            }
        });
    }
}
```